# WatchKit: How to animate Images stored in Nsmutablearray dynamically in objC

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode-6.2, wkinterfaceimage

*Here is my doubt !!!*

**How to run the gif image directly from nsmutablearray which i stored images dynamically by assigning it to Wkinterfaceimage ???**

Currently i'm working on the GIf Images assigning to the wkinterfaceimage.
I stored set of images in a Mutablearray in run time by converting a gif image. How to assign that array to wkinterfaceimage to show run gif image.
i found couple of tutorials in swift tried to implement in OBJ C, Plz let me know ur ideas and code in **Objective C**

Here is my code

```
 [imageView setImage:[frames objectAtIndex:0]];

 [imageView startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,frames.count) duration:1 repeatCount:0];
```

*using above code showing blank screen on similator, if commented second line showing 0 index image.*

**Results of Frames rate**

```
 2015-04-08 10:21:53.206 WatchkitDemo WatchKit Extension[852:24553] {
     DelayTime = "0.1";
     UnclampedDelayTime = 0; }
```

**Results of Frames array**

```
2015-04-08 10:21:58.807 WatchkitDemo WatchKit Extension[852:24553] (
    "<UIImage: 0x7fe358d2d320>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7fe358f05d60>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7fe358f08230>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7fe358d2fd50>"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to convert gif image received from server into an array. I think [Mayoff's UIImage Category](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif) can help you. I can give you an idea for what you can do:

1) Receive **gif** with *either* of the methods defined in category:

```
+[UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:(NSData *)data]
+[UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:(NSURL *)url]
```

2) Go in the implementation file **UIImage+animatedGIF.m**. At [line#89](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/blob/master/uiimage-from-animated-gif/UIImage%2BanimatedGIF.m#L89), method `animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFImageSource` has been implemented. A method `createImagesAndDelays` has been called there to create array of images. It is storing separated images in variable declared as `CGImageRef images[count]`.

You can make this variable an instance variable, or make static method return an array of splitted gif images.

3) Convert those images in the format accepted by `Wkinterfaceimage`.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Buddy @iAnum  .. i will work on this and get back to u :)